# Ubuntu 18.04 - no login screen it stay black screen

Tags: 18.04

I have a little problem with my Ubuntu 18.04 desktop, when it boots, it stays on a black screen and it's writing

```
/dev/sda2: clean, xx/xx files, xx/xx blocks
```

I can have access to a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>. But no login screen.

Comment: In the boot.log, I have a FAILED to start GNOME Display Manager

Answer (score 1):

I have remove the nvidia drivers

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge 'nvidia.*'
```